# Exporting a global variable from child to parent in shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, centos

Is it possible to export a variable from a parent shell script to its children ?
Trying the execute the two following scripts it always returns to me 0 but I want it to return 3. I`ve also tried to export, set and add the variable error to the .bash_profile without success...

test.sh

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
error=0
./envtest.sh
echo $error
```

envtest.sh

```
$ cat envtest.sh
#!/bin/bash
source ./test.sh
test=3
error=$test
echo $error
```

Comment: Have you tried sourcing the file?
    . ./envtest.sh

Comment: No; you cannot affect the parent's environment from a child process.

Comment: You use the phrase "global", which is probably where you misunderstand what exported variables are.  They reside in a block of memory called the *environment block*, so they are known as *environment variables*.  Each process has its own environment block.  It is one of the areas **copied** from parent to child when a new process is created ("forked").  So the child is operating on a copy, environment variables are not global or shared.

Comment: Parent-to-child is exactly what `export` does. You appear to be asking about child-to-parent.

Comment: Yes it loops on the envtest.sh twice and gives me 3, 3, 0 as output.

Comment: @chepner 15 You are right ! Just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @chepner commented, no.

When you invoke `./envtest.sh` from within `test.sh`, a new process is created to run `/bin/bash ./envtest.sh`, and that process's environment is initialized with a *copy* of every environment variable from the parent process.  No matter what you do inside `envtest.sh`, it can only impact the variables within its own environment; it cannot touch the variables in the parent's environment.

Comment: So I need to save whatever variable I am using into an external file so I can use it.

Comment: There are many ways to pass data between processes.  You can use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), [I/O redirection and piping](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), save the data to a file, save to a database, set up an HTTP service to publish data to clients, ...